# Unable to use geoNear in my nodeJS application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mern, get-request

I'm unable to use the geoNear function in my nodeJS application.

```
Ninja.aggregate([
        {
            $geoNear: {
                near: {
                    type: "Point",
                    coordinates: [parseFloat(req.query.lng), parseFloat(req.query.lat)]
                },
                distanceField: "dist.calculated",
                spherical: true,
                maxDistance: 100000

            }
        }
    ])
        .then(function (ninja) {
            res.send(ninja);
        }).catch(next);
```

Error obatined:
{
"error": "geo near accepts just one argument when querying for a GeoJSON point. Extra field found: $maxDistance: 100000.0"
}

Answer (score 0):

Please check your input values for req.query.lng, req.query.lat
Keep coordinates as [longitude, latitude]

```js
$geoNear: {
  near: {
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [ <LONGITUDE>, <LATITUDE>]
  },
  distanceField: "dist.calculated",
  spherical: true,
  maxDistance: 100000
}
```

where,
LONGITUDE ranges from -180 to 180,
LATITUDE ranges from -90 to 90
Please make sure you have received valid latitude and longitude

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I'm still unable to get the desired output. I need help figuring out why the code is not working as expected.

Comment: Are you still with the same error state or its been solved but your output is not correct or did not meet the expected result.

Comment: The previous error is solved but the output obtained is not as expected.